# Prove the unique existence of a unit vector field in an orientable Riemannian manifold with boundary.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be an orientable Riemannian manifold with boundary, prove the unique existence of a unit vector field $X$ on $M$, such that for any point $p\in\partial M$, $X_{p}$ is inward-pointing and orthogonal to $T_{p}(\partial M)$.

I'm not sure whether my idea is right, but I guess by solving some ordinary partial equations we may get the unique existence, but I don't how to build them, and I don't know how to use the condition of Riemann metric, so can someone give me some hints? thanks.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a smooth unit vector field $X$ that is 1. Orthogonal to the boundary of $M$ and inward-pointing, 2. Defined _only in some collar neighborhood_ of the boundary, and 3. _Auto-parallel_ (i.e., $\nabla_X X = 0$, i.e., the flow lines of $X$ are unit-speed geodesics of $(M, g)$)...?

Comment: @ Andrew D. Hwang actually it's a question picked from my textbook, and I translate it literally from Chinese to English and post it here, there seem to be some mistakes with the original question, and thanks for you comment.

Comment: What if the vector field X is on δM instead of M? I think that was the intended question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no condition imposed at interior points of $M$ there is no reason for such a vector field to be *unique*.  For example, on a half-cylinder (with boundary $S^1$) you could construct tons of such vector fields.  If you meant that the value of the vector field along the boundary is unique, this follows from the fact that there is a unique normal direction at each point of $T_p(\partial M)$ (since the "opposite" direction points outward rather than inward).  This question seems more elementary than looking at ODEs.

For example on the half-cylinder $M$ one can choose any smooth function $\theta(p), p\in M$ which vanishes along the boundary, and modify any given vector field $V(p)$ by rotating $V(p)$ by angle $\theta(p)$ so one can't possibly expect uniqueness.

Also, in general there may not be such a vector field on all of $M$.  For example, on the unit disk there is no nonvanishing vector field extending the inward normal along the boundary.  This easily follows from [Brouwer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: the vector field need to be smooth and $M$ has a Riemann metric, do they give some restricts so as to induce the unique exsitence?

Comment: Actually, this question is picked from my textbook, the counterexample you constructed in paragraph 3 is suffice to prove there may be some mistakes with the question, so, thanks for the help:)

Comment: What if the vector field $X$ is on $\delta M$ instead of $M$? I think that was the intended question.